# Calling static methods on classes, given class name as a string

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to find a way to shorten the following block of code.

```
private function getFruit($class, $id)
{
    if ($class === 'Apple') {
        return Apple::findOrFail($id);
    } elseif ($class === 'Orange') {
        return Orange::findOrFail($id);
    } elseif ($class === 'Pear') {
        return Pear::findOrFail($id);
    } elseif ($class === 'Banana') {
        return Banana::findOrFail($id);
    } elseif ($class === 'Mango') {
        return Mango::findOrFail($id);
    }
}'
```

I would love to simplify it to this.

```
private function getFruit($class, $id)
{
    return $class::findOrFail($id);
}
```

But that doesn't work. Is there a way to call a static method on a class, given only the class name? For what it's worth, all of the classes in my example extend a class providing the 'findOrFail' method.

Comment: The obvious question is what version of PHP are you using.  See this [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a86035bbbbfaa892d94ac241bd0065705166f33d) Which works in all versions above PHP5.2

Comment: Other obvious question is what "doesn't work" means in your case.

Comment: `$class::all();` works for me, where `$class = "User";`.

Comment: `Apple::find()` and `${"Apple"}::find()` (which also works) is not the same if `"Apple"` is really `"Namespace\Apple"` in Modern versions of PHP it's preferred to do `$class = Apple::class;`

Comment: Is `findOrFail` a public method of your Fruit classes?

Comment: `findOrFail()`—It's probably a Laravel Eloquent model? Which means that namespacing is probably a factor here, at a guess. Something like `App\Mango` etc.

Comment: In Laravel, a lot of custom defined classes extend `Model`, which has `findOrFail()`.

Comment: Without knowing what this means `But that doesn't work` and what if any errors are raised, it's just guessing, but the best guess here is a Namespace issue.  `if(!class_exists($class)) throw new Exception("Class $class not found")`  if that throws an exception, your class name is wrong (and/or missing the namespace).

Comment: Try `return ('\App\\'.$class)::findOrFail($id);`